# Split a custom UIView in different colors

Tags: ios, swift

I made this stepped progress bar from storyboard and I configure the number of steps (max 8) programmatically by passing an array of strings (each string add a step so a label and the icon).

The white view is the base view and the green view is the progress bar which is of course an UIView.

To animate the progress I simply set the width constraint of the progress bar (I can animate it for a percentage of a specified step).

Now, my goal is to split the progress bar in different colors for each steps:

For example the "Primo" step could have a blue color, the second a red color and so on, each step a different color.

I bet I should subclass a UIView for the progress bar and in the draw method do the magic, but my goal is passing an array of steps (UIStackView) to the bar and with a method say setColor(forStep:1, color: .blue) given the frame.width of the specified step.

Could you help me?

Bests.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add layers inside `UIView.layer` like following -

```
class CustomProgress: UIView {
    var layersCache: [Int: CALayer] = [:]
    
    func setColor(forStep step: Int, color: UIColor) {
        let stepLayer: CALayer
        if let layer = layersCache[step] {
            stepLayer = layer
        } else {
            stepLayer = CALayer()
            layersCache[step] = stepLayer
        }
        
        let size = self.bounds.size
        let stepWidth = size.width / 8 /// totalSteps
        stepLayer.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(step) * stepWidth, y: 0, width: stepWidth, height: size.height)
        
        stepLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        self.layer.insertSublayer(stepLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) It would be best to say something like "set this color from this position in the frame width from now on " on customProgress.setColor passing as parameter the UIStackView (the step itself). Drawing with code is awful lol